Custom errors on formControl are not shown on template
I have a simple scenario, where I am trying to show error from server to field level. But error are not shown on template. Following is the code and package.json contents

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
            <ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.controls['username'].errors !== null ">
                {{formGroup.controls['username'].errors['err']}}
            </ng-container>
        </form>
    `,
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgIf
    ],
})
export class AppComponent {
    formGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor() {
        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
            username: new FormControl(),
        }) ;

        // load data from server
        const errorFromServer = 'Username already exists';
        this.formGroup.controls['username'].setErrors({'err': errorFromServer});
        if (this.formGroup.controls['username'].errors) {
            // Following line displays error on the browser console but no error is shown on template
            console.log(this.formGroup.controls['username'].errors);
        }
        // Updated formgroup value
        this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
        // still no error is shown on template
    }
}



Wrap the logic with the setTimeout function and it will work. Here is stackblitz working demo. Also it is recommended to use 99.9% of times ngOnInit lifecycle hook.
  constructor() {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl(),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.formGroup.controls['username']?.setErrors({
        err: 'username already exists!',
      });
    });
  }


You are looking for asyncValidator of reactive forms, this is suited for handling validations based on API calls (async calls). Below is a forked example highlighting the same.
Async Validator Angular Docs Reference
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'name': [
        // initial value
        null,
        // sync built-in validators
        Validators.compose(
          [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3) ],
        ),
        // custom async validator
        this.service.userValidator()
      ],
    });
  }


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap  } from 'rxjs/operators';

const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserValidators {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  searchUser(text) {
    // debounce
    return timer(1000)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          // Check if username is available
          return this.http.get<any>(`${URL}/users?username=${text}`)
        })
      );
  }

  userValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {
      return this.searchUser(control.value)
        .pipe(
          map(res => {
            // if username is already taken
            if (res.length) {
              // return error
              return { 'userNameExists': true};
            }
          })
        );
    };

  }

}

Forked Stackblitz Demo

Then what's the purpose of control.setErrors({}) method?

@Atif use it as a last resort, this method is more favorable, since it is a function that is automatically triggered on form changes, else you need a lot of extra code to trigger this logic on form changes. also some more logic to prevent the function called multiple times

@Atif if the async validators does not suit your requirements you can build your own validator, but you need to write the extra code that async validators abstracts for you
